# undefined reference to `ceilf'

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to "make" a program and yet face these errors; I used make -lm and even did #include  but still I face the same problem. I tried installing the application on both Ubuntu and Debian just to make sure I remove doubts on corrupted libraries.Still no success !

```
nat_src_endpoint_ip.o: In function `__new':
    /root/softwares/sweetspot-0.0.20/src/nat_src_endpoint_ip.c:95: undefined reference to `ceilf'
    nat_src_endpoint_tcp.o: In function `__create':
    /root/softwares/sweetspot-0.0.20/src/nat_src_endpoint_tcp.c:58: undefined reference to `ceilf'
    nat_src_endpoint_udp.o: In function `__create':
    /root/softwares/sweetspot-0.0.20/src/nat_src_endpoint_udp.c:59: undefined reference to `ceilf'
    nat_src_endpoint_icmp.o: In function `__create':
    /root/softwares/sweetspot-0.0.20/src/nat_src_endpoint_icmp.c:48: undefined reference to `ceilf'
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    make[1]: *** [sweetspot] Error 1
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/softwares/sweetspot-0.0.20/src'
    make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Are you putting the `-lm` flag at the end of the linker invocation?

Comment: show us your make file or command you use to build

Comment: This is the tar of the project(captive portal),the makefile is too large

http://sourceforge.net/projects/sweetspot/files/sweetspot/0.0.20/sweetspot-0.0.20.tar.gz/download

.................................................

What i did was run : " ./configure "   then i ran  " make " which failed, then i ran "make -lm" which also failed

Answer (score 0):

You should link with the math library. In Gcc this means that you should add `-lm` to the linking command line (if you only use one command line it means that this command line is both for compiling and linking).

Comment: I am really sorry but i don't understand you completely @Hivert, I will show my makefile now...What i did was run " make -lm "  in the command line after doing ./configure

Comment: I ran ``./configure; make`` on my computer. There is clearly a missing ``-lm`` somewhere. However since the ``Makefile`` is auto generated by ``automake/autoconf`` this should be fixed at this level. Unfortunately, I'm not an expert of those tools. I'll try to help but I'm not sure I can.

Comment: Thank you. I will be waiting to know the results of your exploits while trying to fix it to

Comment: I think you should add a new question showing your auto(conf/make) configuration, and asking what to do to use the math library.

Comment: I do have -lm option and I have undefined reference too... on ceilf and log2 function...